# trying to edit SQL via php but keep getting an error

Tags: php, mysql

as far as i can see my code is sound however, I keep getting an error
this is the error

> **Notice**:  Undefined variable: person in
>   **\sql\modify.php** on line **12**

here is my code..

```
<?php
include 'includes/connection.php';

if (!isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $q = "SELECT * FROM people WHERE ID = $_GET[id]";
    $result = mysql_query($q);
    $person = mysql_fetch_array($result);       
    }
?>
<h1>You are modifying A User</h1>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
Name<input type="text" name="inputName" value="<?php echo $person['Name']; ?>" /><br />
Description<input type="text" name="inputDesc" value="<?php echo $person['Description']; ?>" />
<br />
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Modify"/>
</form>
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['sumbmit'])) {   

$u = "UPDATE people SET `Name` = '$_POST[inputName]', `Description` = '$_POST[inputDesc]' WHERE ID = $_POST[id]";
  mysql_query($u) or die(mysql_error());

 echo "User has been modify";
 header("Location: index.php");

}
?>
```

any Thoughts or am im I just blind???

Comment: You're only setting `$person` if your if statement runs.

Comment: You're using $person to populate your Description field; but if the form has been submitted, you're not querying the database, so there's no `$person` defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
include 'includes/connection.php';

// set $person veriable
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $q = "SELECT * FROM people WHERE ID = $_GET[id]";
  $result = mysql_query($q);
  $person = mysql_fetch_array($result);       
}
// if form submit you use update and redirect
else {
  $u = "UPDATE people SET `Name` = '$_POST[inputName]', `Description` =      '$_POST[inputDesc]' WHERE ID = $_POST[id]";
  mysql_query($u) or die(mysql_error()); 

  //echo "User has been modify"; // this not need, bcz execute header('location') redirect you current page
  header("Location: index.php");
  exit(); //use it after header location
}
?>
<h1>You are modifying A User</h1>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
Name<input type="text" name="inputName" value="<?php echo $person['Name']; ?>" /><br />
Description<input type="text" name="inputDesc" value="<?php echo $person['Description']; ?>" />
<br />
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Modify"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you @Lastbyte That worked... :) its the else statement that i messed up... Thank you so much..

Answer (score 0):

You just need to check if you actually got output.

Just a plain example:

```
if ($person): 
?>
<h1>You are modifying A User</h1>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
Name<input type="text" name="inputName" value="<?php echo $person['Name']; ?>" /><br />
Description<input type="text" name="inputDesc" value="<?php echo $person['Description']; ?>" />
<br />
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Modify"/>
</form>
<?php
endif;
```

Remember to always validate your input *and* output, but also if queries you try to run *do* produce a result set.

Comment: When I click on Modify, I am able to see what I can modify, however when i hit sumbmit, i get the error.. I get the error for <?php echo $person['Name']; ?> and <?php echo $person['Description']; ?> sorry should have been more clear

Answer (score 0):

Here's the issue:

```
<?php
include 'includes/connection.php';

if (!isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $q = "SELECT * FROM people WHERE ID = $_GET[id]";
    $result = mysql_query($q);
    $person = mysql_fetch_array($result);       
    }
?>
```

At this point $person is set only if the form hasn't been submitted; but later on:

```
Name<input type="text" name="inputName" value="<?php echo $person['Name']; ?>" /><br />
Description<input type="text" name="inputDesc" value="<?php echo $person['Description']; ?>" />
```

You're using it anyway. If the form has been submitted, then you're going to get the warning you're seeing. What you need to do is something like:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $description = $_POST['description']
} else {
    $q = "SELECT * FROM people WHERE ID = $_GET[id]";
    $result = mysql_query($q);
    $person = mysql_fetch_array($result);       

    $name = $person['name'];
    $description= $person['description'];
    }
```

And then:

```
Name<input type="text" name="inputName" value="<?php echo $name ?>" /><br />
Description<input type="text" name="inputDesc" value="<?php echo $description; ?>" />
```

The variables are now set either way.

A couple of other things - you're not doing any error checking to see if your query has worked; if the query fails, your code will carry on regardless.

Secondly, the `mysql_` functions are deprecated and will stop working at some point; you should look at moving to using `mysqli_*` or PDO instead.

Comment: I just seen on php dot net the "MYSQLI_*" info.. I am just now learing mysql_ is there any good info out on the interweb about mysqli.????

Comment: I'd suggest the PHP manual pages: http://www.php.net/mysqli - it's easier to switch to mysqli functions, as there are equivalents for most of the functions so there's less re-writing involved.

Comment: Thank you... have a happy holidays!